# choose a select statement based on parameter

Tags: sql-server

I need to pull in certain dates based on which parameter is selected. I can't think of how this is done. Is there something I am missing with this statement or is there a better way?

```
Declare @StartDate int = CONVERT(varchar(8), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -18), 112)
Declare @MonthYear varchar(8) = 2;

select 
case when @MonthYear = 2 then 
(select DateKey as StartDate
FROM dimDate
where IsLastDayOfYear = 'Y'
and DateKey > 20110101
 and DateKey <= CONVERT(varchar(8), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 0), 112)
Order by DateKey desc
)


when @Monthyear = 1 then

(select DateKey as StartDate
FROM dimDate
where IsLastDayOfMonth = 'Y'
and DateKey > 20110101
 and DateKey <= CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) -0, -1),112)
 )
 end
```

Here is the code that "looks" like what I want to happen.(I know it does not work) I just need to return one or the other depending a parameter. One returns the last day of each year and the other the last day of each month

Comment: Use an `IF`. `CASE` is an expression, not a logical flow operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
and DateKey > 20110101 and DateKey <=
    case @MonthYear
        when 1 then
            CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) -0, -1),112)
        when 2 then
           CONVERT(varchar(8), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 0), 112)
    end
```

It looks like the two "branches" of logic only vary for the end of the date range which is easy to encapsulate in a `case` expression. I'm not really sure about `-0` and what the expressions mean though so I've just copied as is from the question. If your queries end up being slow you might want to put a hard upper bound in so the optimizer can definitively limit the search range.